# Opposite of indexBy in lodash/underscore?

Tags: underscore.js, lodash

I have an object with keys

```
 var obj = { a: { fruit: 'Apple' }, b: { fruit: 'Banana' } }
```

I want to quickly move the key (`a / b`) to the value as a property `name`. I can figure out a [quicker way](http://plnkr.co/edit/A18vdZvG84fXPc57ENqe?p=preview) to do it.

```
 _(obj).keys().each(function(key)
 {
     obj[key].name = key;
 })
 var results = _.values(obj);
```

This is not purely for aesthetic reasons, I can't use the function keyword, because it's in an angular expression

Comment: So you want to end up with `{ a: { fruit: 'Apple', name: 'a' }, b: { fruit: 'Banana', name: 'b' } }`?

Comment: oh, you're right, I missed a step in my code sample, I want it as an array. (indexBy goes from array to object, I want the opposite)

Comment: Can you include the specific result you're looking for?

Comment: I did, just a `_.values()` call afterwards.

Comment: Instead of doing `_.values`, you should've used `.map(function(key){obj[ky].name = key; return obj;})`

Comment: @Bergi - right, but I can't use that because I can't use the `function` keyword, I was hoping there was something built-in I missed.

Comment: Can you call a global higher-order function that returns you this functionality?

Comment: @Bergi - I can add custom functions to the scope, but I guess I can just add as a mixin to lodash when I require it.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the way to go if you cannot use function expressions directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for interested people, this is how I ended up doing this:

```
_.mixin({
    toArrayFromObj: function (object, keyName)
    {
        return _(object).keys().map(function (item)
        {
            object[item][keyName] = item;
            return object[item];
        }).value();
    }
});
```

I'll happily take name or implementation suggestions.

Comment: I adapted this to `return Object.keys(object).map((item) => {
    return { [key]: item, ...object[item] };
  });`

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a slightly different solution:

```
_.mixin({
  disorder: function(collection, path) {
    return _.transform(collection, function(result, item, key) {
      if (path)
        _.set(item, path, key);

      result.push(item);
    }, []);
  }
});
```

Thanks to the usage of `_.set`, the key property can also be transferred to a nested property.

```
var indexedBooks = { 
  'a1': { title: 'foo' }, 
  'a2': { title: 'bar' }
};

var books = _.disorder(indexedBooks, 'author._id');
// → [{ 'title': 'foo', 'author': { '_id': 'a1' }},
//    { 'title': 'bar', 'author': { '_id': 'a2' }}]
```

Comment: Yep, that's really nice, I've never seen `_.transform` used in real life :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of inverting lodash's `keyBy` in Typescript.

```
import { List, Dictionary } from 'lodash';

function unkeyBy<T>(object: Dictionary<T>, key = 'id'): List<T> {
  return Object.keys(object).map((item) => {
    return { [key]: item, ...object[item] };
  });
}
```